# stringsteam format syntax

Tags: c++, iostream

I have a function that is supposed to return a formatted string (hh:mm:sec.xxx)
I want the output to display 2 places for hours, 2 places for minutes, and 5 places for seconds (truncated microseconds);

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

std::string getTime(uint64_t time){ //input is in microseconds

unit64_t tempTime = time;
unit64_t hours = (tempTime / 3600000000);
tempTime -= (hours * 3600000000);

unit64_t mins = (tempTime / 60000000);
tempTime -= (mins * 60000000);

double secs = ((double)tempTime / 1000000);

std::string strTime;

 stringstream ss;
 ss << std::setprecision(2)<<hours<<":"
    << std::setprecision(2)<<mins <<":"
    << std::setprecision(2)<<std::setprecision(2)<<secs; 

 strTime = ss.str();
 return strTime;

}
```

could somebody please show me the proper syntax for inputting the values to ss. It compiles and works but I do not get the format I want.

I just now typed this up for this question so if you see typos please forgive me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot about minutes and you probably want 0 decimal precision. Try:

```
ss << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << std::setprecision(0) << hours << ":" 
   << mins << ":" 
   << std::setprecision(3) << secs;
```

Comment: Thanks. How Do I set a fixed space of 2 for hours and 2 for mins?

Comment: You don't want `setprecision` at all; it has no effect on integral types.  And unlike the other manipulators, the effects of `std::setw` only affect the next output; they're not sticky.  So you have to repeat it for each element.  (And once again, an incorrect answer gets plus votes, and is accepted.)

Comment: Well you're right. as I looked further into this I discovered none of the answers were exactly correct for my situation. I want to hold 2 spaces for hours and minutes regardless of value and I want to hold 5 spaces for seconds regardless of value eg(hh:MM:SS.sss) the correct answer is ss << std::fixed <<std::setw(2) << setfill('0')<<hours<<std::setw(2) <<setfill('0')<<minutes<<std::setw(6) <<setfill('0')<<seconds; That is what I needed for my situation

Answer (score 1):

For your integer fields you can use `std::setw(2)` to set the field width and `std::setfill('0')` to zero-pad on the left.

Answer (score 0):

For some strange reason, `precision` has no effect on integral types in
`iostream`.  (This is standard, but it is strange—much of the
`ostream` formatting is based on `printf`, and precision affects the
output integral values there.)

The obvious answer is to define a manipulator which does what you want. 
Something along the lines of:

```
std::ostream&
timeElement( std::ostream& stream )
{
    stream.width( 2 );
    stream.fill( '0' );
    return stream;
}
```

You can then write:

```
ss << timeElement << hours << ':'
   << timeElement << minutes << ':'
   << timeElement << seconds;
```

As a general rule, you rarely use the standard manipulators.  They
should be considered more an example than anything else.  But they
represent physical markup, and what we almost always want is logical
markup.

Also, don't forget to restore the formatting flags to their original
state when you do this.  (I derive all of my manipulators from a base
class that takes care of this for me, restoring the values in its
destructor.  Using a class here would mean that you'd have to write
`timeElement()`, rather than just `timeElement`; when the manipulator
takes an argument, there is no difference.)

Finally: time and date are special cases, and I'd actually use
`strftime` for them.  (But I regularly use the above technique for just
about everything else.)